# Mockito mock throwing a NPE even when the mocks are activated

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, junit4

I am trying to mock a call `baseUtils.getIdentificationType(id.getType().getName())` but the instance `baseUtils` is always null and hence throws NPE when that method is called. I have mocked `baseUtils` and using `Mockito.initMocks(this)`

`Base class`

```
class Base {

    @Inject
    protected BaseUtils baseUtils;

protected void populateIdentification(Person person, final List<Id> issuedIds) {
        List<Identification> identificationList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (issuedIds != null && issuedIds.size() > 0) {
            for (Id id : issuedIds) {
                Identification identification = new Identification();

                // BELOW CALL TO MOCK BUT baseUtils returns null hence NPE in the test 
                String idType = baseUtils.getIdentificationType(id.getType().getName()); 

                if (idType != null) {
                    identification.setType(idType);
                } else {
                    identification.setTypeOther(id.getType().getName());
                }
                identification.setNumber(issuedId.getId());
                if (issuedId.getCountryCode() != null) {
                    CountryCodeEnum codeEnum = CountryCodeEnum.valueOf(govtIssuedId.getCountryCode());
                    identification.setCountry(codeEnum.getName());
                }
                identificationList.add(identification);
            }
            person.setIdentificationList(identificationList);
        }
    }
}
```

`Child.java`

```
class Child extends Base {

...

}
```

`BaseUtils.java`

```
@Component
public class BaseUtils {

    private Map<String, String> idToIdType;

    public BaseUtils() {
        idToIdType = new HashMap<>();
        idToIdType.put("ID1", "A");
        idToIdType.put("ID2", "B");
        idToIdType.put("ID3", "C");
    }

    public String getIdentificationType(String documentType) {
        if (idToIdType.containsKey(documentType)) {
            return idToIdType.get(documentType);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

`TEST`

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ChildTest {

    @Mock
    private BaseUtils baseUtils;

    @InjectMocks
    Child child = new Child();

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    }

    @Test
    public void populateIdentificationTest() {
        Child child = new Child();
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setId("ID_123456");
        UserData userData = createUserData();
        List<IssuedId> issuedIds = userData.getIssuedIds();

        doReturn("ABC").when(baseUtils).getIdentificationType(anyString());  //MOCKED CALL
        child.populateIdentification(person, issuedIds);

        assertNotNull(person.getIdentificationList());
        assertNotNull(person.getIdentificationList().get(0).getNumber());
    }
}
```

I have reviewed other questions and this is how its done there so not sure what am I not following. Some help will be really appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is here:
You use `@InjectMocks Child child = new Child();` to inject your `BaseUtils` Mock. But in your `@Test` you create a new instance of `Child`. Do not do that. Use your `Child` instance you created in `@InjectMocks Child child = new Child();`.